# Why is my rendered video output larger than imported files?

Tags: video, encoding, mp4, render, output

I have imported multiple video files (roughly 3h30min / roughly 11GB).  I have stripped out the Audio and reduced my total cuts to roughly 2m12sec.  I have tried multiple render video output formats, ideally .mp4.

Note:  I understand the Re-scale and Customer Quality options.

My question is:

Why is my default output for a 2 Minute file 12.4GB for a 2min12sec file?  This is larger that the 3h30 min RAW footage I started with.  Can someone confirm this is correct or way off.  If way off, please provide some options for correction?

Thank you very much,